# Django-nonrel: Syntax to Reset an App

Tags: django, django-models, django-nonrel

To reset my app, I ran this:

```
./manage.py reset node
```

It is giving me this error output:

```
WARNING:root:The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/a/mywebsites/django/seperolinux/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/a/mywebsites/django/seperolinux/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/a/mywebsites/django/seperolinux/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/a/mywebsites/django/seperolinux/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/a/mywebsites/django/seperolinux/django/core/management/base.py", line 286, in handle
    app_output = self.handle_app(app, **options)
  File "/home/a/mywebsites/django/seperolinux/django/core/management/commands/reset.py", line 35, in handle_app
    sql_list = sql_reset(app, self.style, connection)
  File "/home/a/mywebsites/django/seperolinux/django/core/management/sql.py", line 107, in sql_reset
    return sql_delete(app, style, connection) + sql_all(app, style, connection)
  File "/home/a/mywebsites/django/seperolinux/django/core/management/sql.py", line 66, in sql_delete
    table_names = connection.introspection.get_table_list(cursor)
AttributeError: 'DatabaseIntrospection' object has no attribute 'get_table_list'
```

How do I reset a Model in Django-nonrel?

Comment: Is this on App Engine or MongoDB?  If App Engine, on dev_appserver or production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
./manage.py reset node
```

> executes *sqlreset* to create DROPT TABLE and CREATE TABLE SQL
>   statements for the given app.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#reset-appname-appname

This does not work with the App Engine Datastore, because the Datastore is schemaless so there is no need for CREATE/DROP table commands.

If you want to delete existing model from the datastore, you can use the [App Engine Development Console](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#The_Development_Console) to delete all entities of the model (just make sure you use the correct port when accessing the Development Console) .

Comment: This is correct for my problem. Apparently the only thing needed/possible in a schemaless database is to delete all saved instances of a Model. Your link shows that this can be done locally at: http://127.0.0.1:8000/_ah/admin